# Configuring media keys volume adjustment tick/step size

Tags: sound

I can change the volume 'steplessly' by dragging the slider, for instance in settings, but when using media keys there is a step size. For my preference, the step size is too big and my preferred volume is often in between steps.

I haven't been able to find a setting to change the step size, for instance I've looked for the `volume-step` option in dconf editor, but it doesn't exist (anymore). Is this a configurable setting anywhere, and if not, what can I recompile to change it anyway?